# How make one query inside of two query?

Tags: mysql, sql, case

[**Table for test on sqfidle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ced8)

In result I want get count rows where `type= '0'` and count rows where `type= '1'`

I have select:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Likes WHERE type= '0'

SELECT count(*) FROM Likes WHERE type= '1'
```

How make one query inside of two query (combine query)?

Also, how to make that the result is in one line with two columns and in result in first column was count rows where type = '0' and in second column was count rows where type = '0'? How to make it?

Comment: Do you want to combine those two query? I didn't really get what you mean :) can you explain further?

Comment: @AnthonySteven yes i want combine two query. First query get count rows where type = '0'. Second query get count rows where type = '1'. I want combine two query becose it two query to one table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following would combine those two queries into one:

```
SELECT l.type, count(*) AS TotalC
FROM Likes AS l
WHERE l.type = '0' or l.type = '1'
GROUP BY l.type
```

Or if you want the results in one record then you could use:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE l.type WHEN '0' then 1 else 0 end) as Type_0,
  SUM(CASE l.type WHEN '1' then 1 else 0 end) as Type_1
FROM Likes AS l
```

Comment: tell me please how make that result was in one line with two column and in result in first column was count rows `where type = '0'` and in second column was count rows `where type = '0'` ? how make it? it really?

Answer (score 0):

If you want result vertical just use UNION

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Likes WHERE id = '11001' AND type= '0' UNION

SELECT count(*) FROM Likes WHERE id = '11001' AND type= '1'
```

If you want result to horizontal you can use join to join the 2 result

```
SELECT count(*),s1.count1
FROM Likes 
JOIN (SELECT count(*) as count1 FROM Likes WHERE id = '11001'AND type= '1') as s1
 WHERE id = '11001' AND type= '0'
```

Here my sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ced8/18